# Weird black spots in rendered view, because of the size

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry, scale

Some weird black spots seem to appear in the render view of the mesh. They also appear in the final render. It is not duplicated vertices or normals. The materials don't have textures, they are simple node materials.
I've come to realize that it's because it's a huge world (dozens of kilometers of diameter) and the plant is a just a very small object. I tried to make the plant very big (the size of the world) and it doesnt have those spots anymore. How do I solve this without having to change the size of the object?

Blender 2.81, cycles render

My computer:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 8-core

GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER

32gb RAM
[image]
[image]

Comment: Or maybe the spots are still there when the plant is big, they're just very small? I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the "Clip Start" and "End" parameters and nothing changed.

Comment: It looks like the sun that is casting shadows needs larger/lesser shadow sampling and bias values.

Comment: Hey @RandomPanda, and where do I do that? I've realized that if I desactivate "cast shadows" in the sun settings, those black spots disappear. But then again, so do all the shadows. But this tells me that the problem is in the source of light, right? where do I change the shadow sampling and bias? I can't find it in the sun settings or in the render settings.

Comment: I tried changing some values in "light paths" in the render properties, but the spots didn't disappear

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: Sorry Chris, but unfortunatelly, I cannot.

Comment: @Daniel Rodrigues, the settings I mentioned can be found through your selected lamp's data at: PROPERTIES EDITOR -> Object Data Properties

Comment: @RandomPanda, I can't find those settings. I only have "color", "strenght", "angle", "max bounces", "cast shadows" and "multiple importance". Are you perhaps in a different Blender version? Mine is 2.81.

Comment: Shadow bias can be found in the object data properties as I mentioned above. What I neglected to add is that shadow sampling can be found in the properties editor, render properties tab, and the settings can be found under the "shadows" panel.

Comment: @RandomPanda, you're in eevee engine and I'm in cycles. In cycles engine, those options don't exist.